# bootstrap modal body and modal footer cover same area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I am trying to understand why does my modal footer starts at the same place where modal body starts.

How can i make it start after modal body ends.

basically i am trying to understand why are the bottons in the footer, save and cancel not lined same as modal body

```
  <div class="modal fade " id="CustomizeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <label class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">CUSTOMIZE ATTRIBUTES TO DISPLAY</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body col-xs-12">
                      <div class="row">
                          <form role="form" >

                              <div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px">
                                  <table class="table table-striped">
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Search Attributes </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Event IDs </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Event Occurrence Location & File Source </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Event Catagory </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Event Type and Aggregation </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> DSMT Information </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Create By, Updated By and Event Description </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Data Quality Issues and Severity </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Event Channel </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </table>
                              </div>
                          </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <div class="col-xs-12" >
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
                                  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block ebtn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
                                  <button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-default ebtn" ng-click="submit()">Save</button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to display everything in the modal straight up and down, adding rows/columns isn't necessary.

Try using this:

```
<div class="modal fade " id="CustomizeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <label class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">CUSTOMIZE ATTRIBUTES TO DISPLAY</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                          <form role="form" >

                              <div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px">
                                  <table class="table table-striped">
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Search Attributes </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Event IDs </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Event Occurrence Location & File Source </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Event Catagory </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Event Type and Aggregation </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> DSMT Information </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Create By, Updated By and Event Description </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Data Quality Issues and Severity </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                                      <td> Event Channel </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </table>
                              </div>
                          </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                              <div class="pull-right">
                                  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block ebtn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="pull-right">
                                  <button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-default ebtn" ng-click="submit()">Save</button>
                              </div>

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>[![enter link description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: ok for this example i don't need rows and columns, but how about when i do need rows and columns?

Comment: If you do need rows and columns add `row` below `modal-body` and then after the `row` you can create your columns `col-xs-12` for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `col-xs-12` is on the body of the modal which makes the body float left.

remove `col-xs-12` and the footer will appear underneath as you are expecting.

Modals have two optional sizes, available via modifier classes to be placed on a `.modal-dialog`. - `modal-lg` and `modal-sm`

Large

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Small

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```